# In Eclipse I'm using JFrame but no Window is appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I started a new project, all the code is right (I think) and no window is appearing. There are no compilation errors, whenever I run the program nothing happens.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

    public static String title = "Tower Defense";  
    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(700, 550);  

    public static void main(String args[]){ 

        Frame frame = new Frame(); 
    }

    public Frame()  { 

        setTitle(title);
        setSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void init(){

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call `init()` method. How can your frame be visible?

Just change your `main` method to:

```
public static void main(String args[]){ 

    Frame frame = new Frame(); 
    frame.init();
}
```

Comment: Hahaha wow... Now I see I accidentally deleted init() from the constructor method. I remembered because of your answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You never make a call to init() in your frame constructor:

```
public Frame() { 
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    **init();**
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`init()` method will never be called in your program.

Set the visibility in your `Frame()` Constructor itself.

```
import javax.swing.*;              
import java.awt.*;        

public class Frame extends JFrame{

public static String title = "Tower Defense";  
public static Dimension size = new Dimension(700, 550);  

public static void main(String args[]){ 

    Frame frame = new Frame(); 
}

public Frame(){

    setTitle(title);
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```